# How to call the timeinterval function from another component in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I have two component like app.js and SetInterval.js. The function will be called when calling the setinterval.js. Now i want to call the timeinterval function from app.js. I'm sharing the below code for your reference.

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SetInterval from './SetInterval';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SetInterval />
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js </code> sadfsdfasdf and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Setinterval.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SetInterval extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        secondsElapsed:0
    }; 
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
getInitialState(){
    return {secondsElapsed:0};
 }
  tick() {
      let secondsElapsed = parseInt(this.state.secondsElapsed) + 1;
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
    console.log(this.state.secondsElapsed)
    if(this.state.secondsElapsed == 10){
        alert(1)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

I have to get the secondsElapsed value on each call of tick function.

Comment: getInitialState is not required for class based components. The render method should display the secondElapsed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what are you trying to do by writing a component for `setInterval`. But it is mandatory for a React Component to have a `render` function.

```
class SetInterval extends React.Component {
  // your code here
  render() {
    return <div>set interval</div>
  }
}
```

It will work now.

Also, do not write `getInitialState` function when you are creating a class by extending it from `Component` class.

Comment: Yeah its working now. Thanks a lot. One i have added React element in import

Comment: I'm integrating oauth with my project to get the refresh token. Is there any best example to get the refresh token.